# How can I access a GWT menubar popup panel / submenu?

Tags: java, gwt, popup, submenu, menubar

I'm trying to add some mouse listeners to the sub menus/ cascading menus of GWT's MenuBar. Sadly, I cannot seem to access the submenu popuppanel directly - the method to do so (getPopup() ) is private. And you can't access it via reflection due to the way GWT compiles.

Adding a mouse listener to the main menu bar (to detect when the mouse is inside the menu bar boundaries) was nice and simple. But I can't figure out any way to add a mouse listener to tell when the mouse is inside one of the cascading sub menus.

What I am doing is this:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuBar myMainBar = new MenuBar();
myMainBar.addDomHandler(menuHoverOutHandler, MouseOutEvent.getType());
myMainBar.addDomHandler(menuHoverOverHandler, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```

This works great for the actual GWT MenuBar. When I mouse in, the mouseOverEvent triggers. When I mouse out, the MouseOutEvent triggers.

The problem is that if I open a submenu from the main menubar, mousing into that menu will also trigger the MouseOutEvent. I need it not to do that.

When I say submenu I mean something like the ones seen here:

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html

So as long as I'm in the 'main' bar that lists Style, Fruit, and Term, the mouse events recognize this.

But if I drop down to the sub menu that says Bold, Italicized, More, the mouse events believe I have left the menu bar entirely. I need a way to determine if the mouse is inside one of these submenus. (Or that a submenu of this main menu bar is open somewhere)

You cannot simply do

```
myMainBar.getPopup()
```

and add listeners to the resulting PopupPanel as getPopup is private. I'm looking for another way to get to MenuBar.popup

It seems there is no method to tell if one of the sub menus is open, as well, which is a bit perplexing to me. There seems to be a frustrating lack of ability to interact with these submenus, and I am wondering if I am missing something.

Comment: how can I access your code? :) Please can your share some piece of code that tells about what are you doing?

Comment: I have added some code showing what I am doing and some additional explanation. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I'm facing exactly this problem at the moment...

Comment: Why don't you just add `DomHandler`s to your submenus? If you look at the example section of the [MenuBar javadocs](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html#Example), you can see the `MenuBar` being built by cascading `MenuBar`s. What is stopping you from adding `DomHandler`s to those child `MenuBar`s?

Comment: A long time ago, I had a similar issue, and if I remember I have to override the onBrowser event, and cancel events on widgets that do not have to fire the event. I can maybe provide an example this weekend.

Comment: Can't you just ignore (cancel) the MouseOutEvent in your handler if the mouse is currently in a submenu?

Comment: @SteveK: I think the issue is that OP doesn't know how to ignore it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a `MouseOverHandler` and `MouseOutHandler` to each of your submenus as opposed to your main menu bar it should do what you want.

For example:

```
MenuBar subMenu = new MenuBar(true);
subMenu.addItem("Item1", new Command() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        Window.alert("Item1 clicked");
    }
});

subMenu.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent arg0) {
        Window.alert("SubMenu over!");
    }
}, MouseOverEvent.getType());

subMenu.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent arg0) {
        Window.alert("SubMenu out!");
    }
}, MouseOutEvent.getType());

MenuBar mainMenu = new MenuBar();
mainMenu.addItem("SubMenu", subMenu);

RootPanel.get().add(mainMenu);
```

Comment: OP could use this to set a flag and have it ignore the MouseOutEvent in the main menubar if your submenu is 'popped out'.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to the logic of events it self: you would like to have a new type of event that triggers only when the mouse moves out of menus and doesn't if it moves between menus.

To do this you could add code that listens to both mouve over and mouse out and compile the available information to understand what is happening.

You can be sure to execute a code after all events passed by using a [Scheduler](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html)

```
 Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Command() {
    public void execute () {
      //check all what happened in a static shared variable, there was a mouse out, was there a mouse over after it? if yes then stay calm; If there wasn't, then trigger a MouseOutOfAllMenus event
    }
  });
```

this code snippet should be put inside the `onMouseOut()`, and another code that only updates the state of the static class instance should be put in the `onMouseOver()`. You can be sure the code in the `Scheduler.execute()` will execute after the `onMouseOver()` executed thanks to the Scheduling deferred mechanism. So when you will come to check the state, it will be after the mouse entered to another menu (or didn't); therefore you can know if the user really left the menu items or he entered to a submenu.

Last recommandation: do this code in a separate class so you can have this enrichened menu available as a component for future use. Also keep in mind that by keeping things separate you can test and run automated test scenarios a lot easier.

I hope you understood all I tried to explain, if not, feel free to comment, I'll try my best to answer you

Best Regards,

p.s: when i say a static instance state, it's just for the ease of understanding. It is naturally recommended to avoid the static use to be able to have more than one menu in the same application. By static I mean: an instance that is acessible to all of the components